# rails error, wrong number of arguments 2 for 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I am following along on the railstutorial by Michael Hartl. I skipped a chapter out as was advised if desired, I am getting the same error on the User model in the `rails test` for both the `AccountsActivationsController` and `PasswordResetsController`, wrong number of arguements (2 for 1).

Ive spent a bit of time on this trying to see where I went wrong but thought I would ask a outsiders point of view. I am getting the error, on the same action in the user model `def authenticated?` from `valid_user` and `edit` actions in their respective controllers.

What may be the problem?

AccountsActivationsController

```
class AccountsActivationsController

    def edit
      user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
        user.activate
        user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
        user.update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
        log_in user
        flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
        redirect_to user
      else
        flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
end
```

PasswordResetsController

```
class PasswordResetsConrtoller
   .
   .
   .

    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
   .
   .
```

User model

```
class User
   .
   .
   .

    def authenticated?(activation_token)
      return false if activation_digest.nil?
      BCrypt::Password.new(activation_digest).is_password?(activation_token)
    end
   .
   .
```

Comment: Why are you passing in two parameters when it clearly takes one? You even have the code right there where *only* `activation_token` is a valid argument.

Comment: Not sure, thats what it said in the tutorial. What should it have there, you reackon?

Comment: You should be passing just the token, so if that's `params[:id]` then so be it. The tutorial is broken.

Comment: The tutorial actually puts this in the "authenticated?" method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840503/getting-error-invalidhash-in-hartl-tutorial-for-valid-user) but this still produces a error. I thought there would be a way to get the method to work for both arguements.

Comment: That other example looks correct, it takes two arguments. This one takes just one, and it doesn't even look like it's testing the right thing.

Comment: no, still learning following along and getting stuck at times. :) The other question I am still abit confused :S but learning slowly.

Comment: Learning's what matters here. You'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two arguments to `User#authenticated?` method, whereas it accepts only one.

Also, it has nothing to do with your tests. It seems a syntax error.

Comment: it is not a syntax error, is the `ArgumentError` error.

Comment: Could, you please, explain to me where I am adding in two arguments is it in line `BCrypt::Password.new(activation_digest).is_password?(activation_token)`?

Comment: Pleasw see `user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])` and `@user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id])`. You are passing two arguments, but the method takes only one.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to pass `params[:id]` just pass the `:reset`.I think it will work for you.